# Nodejs ODBC Connection on Windows

Tags: windows, node.js, odbc

I have a project that would be perfect for Node.js, but it has to connect to a ODBC database and it has to run on windows. I see ODBC modules for nodejs on linux, but not windows. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Well, I had to program my own in Visual C++ and add it as a node.js addon. It works okay for now.

Comment: I think writing the add-on you were looking for entitles you to both give yourself the answer and a shame-free plug with a link to the add-on.

Comment: Ha ha, maybe you are right Erik, but the addon is so crappy right now I wouldn't want to own it. My c++ skills are pretty bad. And even worse, it ended up not bing asynchronous which really defeated my point. I ended up using python which has great odbc support on windows :-)

Answer (score 5):

If you're like me and arrived here from Google, because you have old (ie ancient) systems, I came across [Is it possible to marry WSH (wscript) with nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267265/is-it-possible-to-marry-wsh-wscript-with-nodejs) and was alerted to the npm module "win32ole": https://www.npmjs.com/package/win32ole.

While not just an ODBC solution, "win32ole" does give you the ability to do quite a lot on a windblows box, just like the old WSH did.

```
var win32ole = require('win32ole');
. . .
// Create an ADODB.Connection Object
dbcon = new ActiveXObject('ADODB.Connection');
```

If (like me), you're after an ODBC connection because you're connecting to an access DB, then there's even a sample script to connect using Jet directly:

https://github.com/idobatter/node-win32ole/blob/master/examples/access_mdb_sample.js

Edit: It does require a node-gyp, a module that requires building code to native...

Answer (score 3):

The state of database drivers for node.js on Windows seems somewhat immature compared to the robust and highly performant database drivers we have had available in ADO.NET for years.

I would seriously consider using [Edge](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) to call C# or a CLR assembly in-process to access your database. You could write a [Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) style data access layer in C# and call it from node.js.

I have proven this works in a development context with C#, [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) (optional), .NET 4.5 and the Oracle ODP driver (Oracle.DataAccess.dll), and with ADO.NET + SQL Server. This should work with any database that you can talk to in .NET.

Node (server.js) example to call .NET CLR function:

```
var edge = require('edge');

// define CLR function proxy
var getData = edge.func({
    assemblyFile: '../Repositories/bin/Debug/Repositories.dll',
    typeName: 'Repositories.TestRepository',
    methodName: 'GetData' // This must be Func<object,Task<object>>
});

// call proxy function
getData({ myParam:1 }, function (error, result) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(result);
});
```

GetData C# looks like this (note you need to put your connection string in node.exe.config in the folder that contains node.exe):

```
public async Task<object> GetData(object param)
    {
        using (var db = new Database("NameOfConnString"))
        {
            return db.Fetch<dynamic>("SELECT * FROM sometable");
        }
    }
```

Alternately, if using SQL Server, you can use [edge-sql](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge#how-to-script-t-sql-in-a-nodejs-application).

Node example (server.js) using edge-sql (note you need to put your connection string into an environment variable as per edge-sql docs):

```
var edge = require('edge');

// edge-sql has built in support for T-SQL / MSSQL Server
var getData = edge.func('sql', function () {/*
    select top 10 * from sometable
*/
});

getData(null, function (error, result) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Things have changed a lot since 2015. I'd now recommend mssql npm package.

Answer (score 3):

The [node-odbc](https://github.com/markdirish/node-odbc) sais it is unixODBC for Linux, but it works in Windows too, I am using it here.
It just does not include the binaries, so you need to install windows-build-tools and node-gyp before installing node-odbc, in order to build the binaries.

```
npm i -g windows-build-tools
npm i -g node-gyp
npm i odbc
```

Comment: This works without any other configuring after these packages are installed.  Just make sure you install in the order above.  If you need a code snippet example, I used this as a template: https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/square-odbc-nodejs.rst

Answer (score 2):

I am starting node.js , been sick of csript.exe is the main reason.
It's damn powerfull, and very impressive, took me 1h to set up a whole grid fully functionnal . Well I am not here to promote node.js , I am noob on it.
I find out however something very usefull... 
http://syskall.com/how-to-write-your-own-native-nodejs-extension/

So rather than redoing what C++ will always do better, I use both node.js and C++ for maximum efficiencies that way.

Answer (score -10):

<strike>NodeJS has some potential but it is still a toy. The idea that a frontend programmer and backend programmer are interchangeable is laughable. But that is off topic...</strike>

Microsoft [released](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/archive/2012/06/08/introducing-the-microsoft-driver-for-node-js-for-sql-server.aspx) their own driver(s). I have not tried them so I have no idea how good they are. I imagine that they must be somewhat good as I have seen multiple job postings for NodeJS programmers in the last 8 months. (also not responsive).

Comment: That link is to the native SQL Server driver, not a generic ODBC driver for Windows (which doesn't appear to exist).

Comment: While node.js is still a toy, it fits a great use case right now. DB wrapper that exposes a web api. It was designed from the ground up to be asynchronous and it is in large production apps already. Here is an older article: http://blog.appfog.com/node-js-is-taking-over-the-enterprise-whether-you-like-it-or-not/

Comment: You've never met anybody who could handle both?

Comment: @Richard About your "laughable..." comment. I'm an ex-Microsoft developer and have found node.js to be extremely useful front to back in a scalable way and am running 3 of my companies off of it. I replaced many I/O intensive areas of .NET with node.js and can sleep better.

Comment: @Richard, a toy? Not anymore. The days were backend programmers could kick front end programmers around is over.

Comment: I feel old, but once upon a time there was no difference between front-end and back-end developers. Somehow we managed to do both jobs.