# SVCode Extension with ODBC

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, odbc, vscode-extensions

I try to execute SQL queries from my Visual Studio Code Extension.
I know there is an [vscode-mssql extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-mssql) out there for SQL-Server, but I need ODBC connection from my extension.
I was expected to work with this [odbc package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odbc), but it only works for linux.

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017024/libraries-for-connecting-node-js-to-odbc-on-windows) I installed it but I get an error as I expected:

> Activating extension failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

So, how can I connect to ODBC ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nodejs ODBC Connection on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489465/nodejs-odbc-connection-on-windows)

Comment: As long as VSCode is a JS engine and it uses Nodejs , please vote it as duplicate of this detailed post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489465/nodejs-odbc-connection-on-windows